# Unable to dynamically modify content of a page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I need to change some `opengraph` attributes on a specific page based on the query string.

I tried to use some filters based on a installed plugin in the `functions.php`:

```
function update_the_og_title($content) {
  if(is_page('the-page')) {
     // Modify the tags
  } else{
    // Do nothing
  }
}
```

However, I soon found out the `functions.php` cannot detect a page using `is_page()`. What should I do?

How else can I dynamically modify the `opengraph` tags of a page in WordPress?

Thanks.

Comment: First you need to know where your OG tags come from. He could be from template/plugins/hooks. Then is_page should work in functions but it may not depend on the hook you are using for update_the_og_title (BTW you should use your function with an hook/action otherwise - if it's not the case - it will never be called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use is_page but not when functions.php is initially included. What you want to do is to run your code at a specific point in the WP process, using a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/):

```
function update_the_og_title() {
    $id = get_the_id(); // 
    if(is_page($id)) {
        // Get your content here, maybe from metadata?
        // Modify the tags
    } else{
        // Do nothing
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'update_the_og_title');
```

[Wordpress action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

You can get the page ID in a number of ways, including using the [$post variable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170358/when-to-use-global-post-and-other-global-variables) depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @David. Is the detection of `is_page()` hook specific? For example, I tried hooks from two different plugin. One was able to change the content while other couldn't. They were both meant to modify the page output.

Comment: It just needs to be run at the right time. If it's going to be dynamic then it needs to be run on the current page (I assume) which means it needs to be run after the code that Wordpress uses to build the page/post objects. the 'wp' hook is the right place to do that. It runs after the object setup, but before anything is displayed.